# Mysql: change the column value based on column's previous value

Tags: mysql

I want to update the column expiry_date only if the already stored expiry_date is less than new expiry_date how to achieve this is mysql

```
  update tbl_user 
  set 
     email="sdhfids@gmail.com' 
     currency="USD" 
     expiry_date=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$expiry_date." MONTH) 
  where user_id=1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See GREATEST (or WHERE, I guess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this USING `CASE`

```
update tbl_user 
 set 
 email='sdhfids@gmail.com' 
 currency='USD' 
 expiry_date= CASE WHEN expiry_date < 'UR NEW DATE' 
                       THEN  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$expiry_date." MONTH) 
                   ELSE   expiry_date
               END      
 where user_id=1
```

Comment: Hello Bro, Thanks for your answer can I change this CASE WHEN expiry_date < 'UR NEW DATE'  to CASE WHEN expiry_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$expiry_date." MONTH)

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan `'UR NEW DATE'` can be replace to comparison value. and if your new date value is  `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$expiry_date." MONTH)` then yes it can be replace

Answer (score 1):

As @Strawberry commented, GREATEST should work:

```
update tbl_user 
set 
 email="sdhfids@gmail.com' 
 currency="USD" 
 expiry_date=GREATEST(expiry_date, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$expiry_date." MONTH))
where user_id=1
```